# Ubuntu 13.10 64bit -> 32bit Oracle JDK -> IntelliJ Idea Comm. edition: HOW?

Tags: java, android, ubuntu, intellij-idea

the scenario is fairly complex.
I have a machine with Ubuntu 13.10 installed and want to use IntelliJ Idea community edition, for android development and therefore with the 32bit version of the Oracle JDK.

Already installed the JDK and added it to alternatives. Problem is, I cannot get Idea to start anyhow.
Error something like that: "cannot initialize class java.awt.toolkit"
I searched for hours, finding solutions by installing some missing libraries using apt-get, but nothing helped yet.

As I'm kind of desperate, I'm asking if someone has a solution for me? Maybe as well, I could just use the 64 bit JDK and am good to go?

Kind regards

Comment: If your OS is 64bit you should really use a 64bit JDK. Nothing prevents you afterwards to use _other_ JDKs in your projects if you want to.

Comment: Makes sense somehow ^^ ... Will try to start the IDE running 64bit using the 32 version for development. Weird that this idea didn't come to my mind.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`sudo apt-get install libxtst6:i386`

But there should be nothing wrong with using a 64bit JDK, actually I would encourage you to install and use it.

Comment: Already tried that one. Doesn't help for me. Regarding the 64bit JDK you just alway read online, that it's not the best choice for Android Development(?)

Comment: I would give it a try. Which IDE are you planning to use?

Comment: IntelliJ Idea; I'll give it a try!

Comment: Both Android Studio (by IntelliJ) and IntelliJ Idea should work flawless on Ubuntu 64